# About C# Expression.MakeBinary(),how to use

Tags: c#, expression

About `Expression.MakeBinary()`

```
BinaryExpression MakeBinary (
    ExpressionType binaryType, 
    Expression left, 
    Expression right, 
    bool liftToNull,
    MethodInfo method
);
```

sample:

```
        return Visit(expression);  
    }  

    protected override Expression VisitBinary(BinaryExpression b)  
    {  
        if (b.NodeType == ExpressionType.AndAlso)  
        {  
            Expression left = this.Visit(b.Left);  
            Expression right = this.Visit(b.Right);  

            // Make this binary expression an OrElse operation instead of an AndAlso operation.  
            return Expression.MakeBinary(ExpressionType.OrElse, left, right, b.IsLiftedToNull, b.Method);  
        }
```

Microsoft documentation explanation：`b.IsLiftedToNull` true if the operator's return type is lifted to a nullable type; otherwise, false.

I don't understand what that means,What effect does true or false have?
What does `b.Method` do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.expressions.binaryexpression?view=netframework-4.8) for `BinaryExpression` itself is helpful to answer these questions.

Note that there are three overloads for this method:

`MakeBinary(ExpressionType, Expression, Expression)`

`MakeBinary(ExpressionType, Expression, Expression, Boolean, MethodInfo)`

`MakeBinary(ExpressionType, Expression, Expression, Boolean, MethodInfo, LambdaExpression)`

The one you refer to is the second of the three.

**Lifted Operators**

A lifted operator allows an operator on a non-nullable type to be used with the nullable equivalent as well.

e.g:

`int a = 1; 
int b = 2;
int c = a + b`

Here, the `+` operator is defined for `int, int`.

But:

`int? a = 1; 
int? b = 2;
int? c = a + b`

Here, the `+` operator isn't defined in the language specification for `int?, int?`, and so the compiler "lifts" the operator, allowing it to work in this instance.

So for the question, a `BinaryExpression` "Represents an expression that has a binary operator"; and if `IsLiftedToNull` is true, it would be "Represents an expression that has a nullable binary operator".

**Method**

Instead of relying on a predefined operator, You can specify the method to use for the binary operation here.